# Creating a new class based on existing class

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, northwind

I am referencing my question to Northwind LINQ to SQL C# sample (taken from MSDN):

The database contains a table named `Products` which has a field named `CategoryID`.
Therefore the NorthWindDataClasses.designer.cs file contains a class called `Product` with the following data member:

```
private System.Nullable<int> _CategoryID;
```

There is another table named `Categories` that includes the following two fields:

- `CategoryID`.
- `CategoryName`.

I would like to create a new class (in my Accessor.cs file) which has all the fields as in `Product` class, but instead of `_CategoryID`, there will be `CategoryName`.

What is the best way to implement it?

Comment: Why?  you can't get what you want by Product.Category.CategoryName?

Comment: And doesn't the generated `Product` class contain a public `Category` property?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to add the CategoryName property to the Product class (which is partial and allows you to add to it).

```
public partial class Product
{
  public string CategoryName
  {
    get {return this.Category.CategoryName;}
    set{this.Category.CategoryName = value;}
  }
}
```